# localize inline css

Tags: localization, css

I'm providing a theme setting to define a group of images for the frontpage background. On page load, I want to pick an image at random from this pool.

My approach is to add a line of inline CSS styling the html element with the given image url like this:

```
<style>
  html { 
    background: url(images/random_image_3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
</style>
```

Is there a preferred way of doing this ? Should i use a localize_style function I haven't found out about, or just echo the css out using the right hook?

And what's the best hook for this, only targeting the front facing site?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`wp_head` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) and inject your <style> tag directly into the <head>. Note: make sure you're firing the [`wp_head()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) in your template (which you should be doing already).

```
add_action('wp_head', 'random_background_image_wpse_83275');
function random_background_image_wpse_83275() {
    $images = array(
        '/path/to/image1.jpg',
        '/path/to/image2.jpg',
        '/path/to/image3.jpg',
        '/path/to/image4.jpg',
    );

    $image = $images[rand(0, count($images)-1)];

    echo '
        <style>
            html { 
                background: url("' . $image . '") no-repeat center center fixed; 
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
            }
        </style>';        
} // END function random_background_image_wpse_83275
```

---

#### Edit

Another option is to [dynamically generate the stylesheet](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/), and randomly choose `$image` in that file. Then you'd inject your stylesheet <link ...> via [`wp_enqueue_scripts` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) (yes, wp_enqueue_**scripts**), and enqueue with [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

Comment: The only property that should be placed in the header is `background-image`. Everything else belongs to the static stylesheet.

Comment: @toscho, I was thinking along those same lines, but figured if Author decides to go a different route later on, it's a simple matter of deleting the function or commenting out the `add_action`, instead of editing both the `functions.php` and the relevant stylesheet. I'll leave it up to the Author to decide which way to go.

Comment: -1 to CSS generated by scripts, you just have no way to cache them, maybe better to randomly include different CSS files

Comment: I see the caching problem, but adding a random css file, has the same problem, as the linkt to the file would be cached.. I guess a little jQuery that sets the css properties is the best way. then it can be randomized clientside, and a cashed page will not look the same each time it's loaded.